# Cannot access created plugins through the builder plugin on OctoberCMS 419 Build

Tags: php, doctrine, octobercms

I've recently moved an OctoberCMS project that I've had stored locally over to a server. Due to the server running PHP 5, I had to downgrade the project to an OctoberCMS version of 419. After getting it running on the server, I try to access any installed plugins through the builder plugin and when I click on one of them in the builder plugin, it outputs the following error:

```
"syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'"
```

This error occurs on line 154 in **"vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php".**

I mean I'm fairly certain that I installed PHP 5 via composer for the CMS, but it looks like the file is based on PHP 7. Any ideas as to why this could be happening? And if it is because of a PHP version issue, then how would I go about fixing that? Apologies if I seem vague. I've been trying to figure it out for a few days now.

Comment: hmm can you share your `composer.json` details its `require` section data.

Comment: `"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "october/rain": "1.0.419",
        "october/system": "1.0.419",
        "october/backend": "1.0.419",
        "october/cms": "1.0.419",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master"
    },`

I searched through the vendor folder and there seems to be more composer.json files, but I don't think they are active unless I run them.

Comment: yes I saw code is of the php 7.0 although `october/rain` should use `dbal version 2.4` and that version is not even have that file there, so must be issue with composer update.

Answer (score 0):

hmm I see as `october/rain` is of version `1.0.419` and it uses `"doctrine/dbal": "~2.4",` but unfortunately its not updated to old version. during that php version update.

can you try one thing from your installation just remove `vendors` folder and `modules`  folder

> 1. make sure if you change any `core code` in modules first take a backup of that file then delete that folder.
> 2. **Backup your database**.
> 3. also config files if needed.

remove `vendors` folder and `modules`  folder

after that `remove your composer lock` file

replace your `package.json` file with this content https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/v1.0.419/composer.json which is of built `.419`

now from that directory run `composer intsall`

it will install all new files based on correct dependency.

**[Current issue is may be due to some dependencies are not updated to old version]**

now just restore all you `config file` [not sure not needed may be as all stuff will be untouched by these process so just check if needed]

now do database migration with this command - `php artisan october:up`

this should start your site.

if you find any problem please comment.

Comment: Apologises for the late reply. I will try your solution at some point next week hopefully once I've got all the content sorted. Thanks for posting and helping me out and I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: nice to hear that but **please make sure you backup every single file and database** as this operation can erase your data.. and we don't want that .. good luck

Comment: I will do. Thanks.